Upgrading systemd from Debian backports safely
I want to upgrade systemd to the one in the Debian backports to fix an issue that was resolved in the newer version.
After adding bullseye backports to apt sources, I tried running sudo apt install systemd/bullseye-backports and got the following result:
$ sudo apt install systemd/bullseye-backports
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Selected version '252.26-1~deb12u2~bpo11+1' (Debian Backports:bullseye-backports [armhf]) for 'systemd'
Selected version '252.26-1~deb12u2~bpo11+1' (Debian Backports:bullseye-backports [armhf]) for 'libsystemd0' because of 'systemd'
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  acl agnostics colord-data cups-ppdc fio fonts-piboto gnome-accessibility-themes gnome-session-bin gnome-session-common gnome-themes-extra gnome-themes-extra-data gnome-themes-standard gtk2-engines-clearlookspix gtk2-engines-pixbuf
  gtk2-engines-pixflat ibverbs-providers iio-sensor-proxy ipp-usb libaio1 libappstream4 libayatana-ido3-0.4-0 libayatana-indicator3-7 libboost-iostreams1.74.0 libboost-thread1.74.0 libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcolorhug2 libcupsfilters1
  libcupsimage2 libgeoclue-2-0 libgeocode-glib0 libgfapi0 libgfrpc0 libgfxdr0 libglusterfs0 libgusb2 libgweather-3-16 libgweather-common libibverbs1 libieee1284-3 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 libmbim-glib4 libmbim-proxy libmm-glib0 libnm0
  libnma-common libnma0 libnuma1 libpoppler-glib8 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libqmi-glib5 libqmi-proxy librados2 librbd1 librdmacm1 libsane-common libsane1 libslirp0 libsnmp-base libsnmp40 libstemmer0d libupower-glib3 libxklavier16
  lightdm-gtk-greeter lxde-common lxplug-bluetooth lxplug-cputemp lxplug-ejecter lxplug-magnifier lxplug-menu lxplug-netman lxplug-network lxplug-ptbatt lxplug-volumepulse pi-greeter pi-language-support pi-package-data
  pi-printer-support pishutdown pixflat-icons printer-driver-escpr rp-bookshelf rpd-plym-splash rpd-wallpaper sane-utils slirp4netns update-inetd upower usb.ids xwayland
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libsystemd-shared libsystemd0
Suggested packages:
  systemd-container systemd-homed systemd-userdbd systemd-boot systemd-resolved libqrencode4 libtss2-esys-3.0.2-0 libtss2-mu0 libtss2-rc0 polkitd | policykit-1
Recommended packages:
  systemd-timesyncd | time-daemon
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  colord dbus-user-session docker-ce-rootless-extras gnome-session-noshell gnome-settings-daemon gui-pkinst libpam-systemd lightdm lxde lxde-core lxplug-updater lxpolkit lxsession lxsession-logout modemmanager openbox-lxde-session
  packagekit pi-package pi-package-session pipanel piwiz policykit-1 raspberrypi-ui-mods rp-prefapps rpi-wayland rtkit systemd-timesyncd
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libsystemd-shared
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libsystemd0 systemd
2 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 27 to remove and 54 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,778 kB of archives.
After this operation, 38.8 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]

The The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required and The following packages will be REMOVED parts alarmed me, especially since aborting and running sudo apt autoremove resulted in no package removal. I'm assuming that proceeding with the above comand would be bad.
After that I tried including the packages under the will be REMOVED section in the install command:
sudo apt install -t bullseye-backports systemd colord dbus-user-session docker-ce-rootless-extras gnome-session-noshell gnome-settings-daemon gui-pkinst libpam-systemd lightdm lxde lxde-core lxplug-updater lxpolkit lxsession lxsession-logout modemmanager openbox-lxde-session packagekit pi-package pi-package-session pipanel piwiz policykit-1 raspberrypi-ui-mods rp-prefapps rpi-wayland rtkit systemd-timesyncd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
colord is already the newest version (1.4.5-3).
colord set to manually installed.
dbus-user-session is already the newest version (1.12.28-0+deb11u1).
dbus-user-session set to manually installed.
lxde is already the newest version (11).
lxde-core is already the newest version (11).
lxde-core set to manually installed.
openbox-lxde-session is already the newest version (0.99.2-4).
openbox-lxde-session set to manually installed.
packagekit is already the newest version (1.2.2-2).
packagekit set to manually installed.
rtkit is already the newest version (0.13-4).
rtkit set to manually installed.
docker-ce-rootless-extras is already the newest version (5:27.0.3-1~raspbian.11~bullseye).
gnome-session-noshell is already the newest version (3.38.0-4+rpt2).
gnome-session-noshell set to manually installed.
gnome-settings-daemon is already the newest version (3.38.2-1+rpt1).
gnome-settings-daemon set to manually installed.
gui-pkinst is already the newest version (0.9).
gui-pkinst set to manually installed.
lightdm is already the newest version (1.26.0-7+rpt1).
lxplug-updater is already the newest version (0.14).
lxplug-updater set to manually installed.
lxpolkit is already the newest version (0.5.5-2+rpt2).
lxpolkit set to manually installed.
lxsession is already the newest version (0.5.5-2+rpt2).
lxsession set to manually installed.
lxsession-logout is already the newest version (0.5.5-2+rpt2).
lxsession-logout set to manually installed.
pi-package is already the newest version (0.8).
pi-package-session is already the newest version (0.8).
pi-package-session set to manually installed.
pipanel is already the newest version (1:1.16).
pipanel set to manually installed.
piwiz is already the newest version (0.43).
policykit-1 is already the newest version (0.105-31+rpt1+deb11u1).
raspberrypi-ui-mods is already the newest version (1.20230127).
rp-prefapps is already the newest version (0.47).
rpi-wayland is already the newest version (0.2).
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libmbim-glib4 libmbim-proxy libmbim-utils libmm-glib0 libqmi-glib5 libqmi-proxy libqmi-utils libqrtr-glib0 libsystemd-shared libsystemd0
Suggested packages:
  systemd-container systemd-homed systemd-userdbd systemd-boot systemd-resolved libqrencode4 libtss2-esys-3.0.2-0 libtss2-mu0 libtss2-rc0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmbim-utils libqmi-utils libqrtr-glib0 libsystemd-shared
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libmbim-glib4 libmbim-proxy libmm-glib0 libpam-systemd libqmi-glib5 libqmi-proxy libsystemd0 modemmanager systemd systemd-timesyncd
10 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 130 not upgraded.
Need to get 7,232 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,509 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]

This time I don't see anything that would immediately trigger alarms in me, but I'm relatively inexperienced, so I'm unsure. Will the above command upgrade systemd safely, in other words, without breaking any existing packages, or am I still missing something?
My question is reallt twofold:

How do I upgrade systemd from the Debian backports (relatively) safely?
How do I tell if an apt command is safe to run in general?

Additional Info:

Model: 3B+
OS: Raspbian bullseye 11 armv7l (32-bit)


Ah... maybe if you had searched for 'backports' you would have come across this answer - which may be of use to you. I know you said you were using the bullseye-backports; I assume that your OS is also bullseye... is that correct?? It will save everyone time if you could add a tag (or note in your Q) that stated which OS version you are using.

Thanks for the suggestion, I added system info. As for the other answer, I'm not asking how to add backports as a source, and install something from there, as I already followed Debian docs, I'm asking how to do it safely, and how to tell if it's safe or not

OK - well then perhaps you should try to define "safe" - otherwise, you're asking for an opinion. I, personally, feel it's very safe. I don't think any other distro can match Debian's apt system for maintaining updates. And if you read the other answer, you'll know there's a way to "undo" upgrades/changes from backports.

If I understood the first example in my question, it would delete a TON on packages, even though I only asked to upgrade 1. So as stated in the question "safely, in other words, without breaking any existing package". I've had broken packages with apt, mainly because of my own mistakes, but that's why I'm here. Also, the whole Linus from LTT fiasco with Pop!_OS is a thing. And finally, you can only undo something if the system isn't bricked in the process. I don't really want to break something with systemd. And yes, the question is opinionated, I realize that.
